# define the path to the chaincode hyperledger-fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I'am trying to change the change code for the hyperledger fabric "first-network", I want to put an other one.
Ididn't find where to define it and what to change.
I know that i have to change the name and put the path to the new chaincode, but i didn't find where

Answer (score 0):

You can find that in docker-compose files folder chaincode (`fabric-samples/chaincode`) is mounted to `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode`
and in the script.sh variable `CC_SRC_PATH` is set to  `github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/` , so if you want to use your own chaincode in the first-network solution you should put it to folder `chaincode` and set up  `CC_SRC_PATH`
this varibles is used in utils.sh file
`peer chaincode install -n mycc -v ${VERSION} -l ${LANGUAGE} -p ${CC_SRC_PATH} >&log.txt`